# jquery.extend(true, [], obj) not creating a deep copy

Tags: javascript, jquery

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/s2bLv/7/).

If deep copying worked, the output would be "Curious George" and not "Ender's Game". How can I make a deep copy? An answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) indicates that `$.extend(true, [], obj)` creates a deep copy. Yet my example shows that it doesn't.

```
function Person(){}
Person.prototype.favorite_books = [];

var george = new Person();
george.favorite_books = ["Curious George"];

var kate = new Person();
kate.favorite_books = ["The Da Vinci Code", "Harry Potter"];

var people = [kate, george];

var people_copy = $.extend(true, [], people);
people_copy[0].favorite_books[0] = "Ender's Game";

$('#text').text(people[0].favorite_books[0]);
```

**SOLUTION**

I updated the jsFiddle. It turns out I need to deep copy each object in the array individually **if the object is a custom object** (that is, `$.isPlainObject` returns false).

Comment: use .clone() see http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: @Paul Sullivan: `.clone()` is to be used with DOM entities

Comment: okay so browse .extend source code and see why the recursive function isn't copying attributes

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object/122704#122704

Comment: @karthikr: have you even read this question and the answer you've referred?

Comment: "It turns out I need to deep copy each object in the array individually." ... if only you're custom objects

Comment: err: `s/you're/you're using/`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

And now here is the **real** answer:

At the moment jQuery can only clone plain JavaScript Objects, while you're using custom ones. And that's obvious, since jQuery cannot know how exactly to instantiate a new custom object. So this works as expected:

```
var george = {};
george.favorite_books = ["Curious George"];

var kate = {};
kate.favorite_books = ["The Da Vinci Code", "Harry Potter"];

var people = [kate, george];

var people_copy = $.extend(true, [], people);

console.log(people_copy[0].favorite_books == people[0].favorite_books);
```

Reference to a jQuery code: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L305

See that it checks if it's `jQuery.isPlainObject(copy)` or it's an array. Otherwise it performs just a reference copy.

Comment: @Rose Perrone: because you have created a deep copy. So the original object is kept as is, and the modified one is modified independently. Not sure what is confusing you.

Comment: @RoyiNamir you specified that it should be a deep copy (the first argument)

Comment: Please check what first boolean argument in `$.extend` function call means. And ask another question if it's still not clear for you.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I've done it after trying many approaches:

```
var newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(orgArray));
```

This will create a new deep copy, not a shallow copy.

Also this obviously will not clone events and functions, but the good thing is you can do it in one line, and it can be used for any king of object (arrays, strings, numbers, objects, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

Interesting....it doesn't look like it deep copies arrays.

You have to deep copy each object individually.

```
var people_copy = [];
$.each(people,function(i,obj) {
    people_copy.push($.extend(true,{},obj)); 
});
```

EDIT: Sure, look at this fork of the OP's fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/s2bLv/4/

Comment: "deep copies objects, not arrays" --- any proofs for that? Isn't array a special kind of object?

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L305 - it should handle arrays

Comment: If you have to deep copy each object individually you would need some recursive code to copy all the way down - unless this is only supposed to cover the OP's simple test case rather than being a generic solution?