# jQuery.extend() deep clone nested objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, extend

I am trying to clone a quite complicated object with nested sub objects.

The object has a structure like this:

- Board has n elements of BoardElement
- BoardElement has n Elements of
  BoardElementUnits

http://pastebin.com/2NgQQXUC

using jQuery.extend():

```
var board = $.extend(true, {}, this.game.board)
```

doesn't clone the nested objects, so I have used JSON to be sure there are no leftover references to the source object.

```
var boardJSON = JSON.stringify(JSON.decycle(this.game.board));
var board =  JSON.retrocycle($.parseJSON(boardJSON));
```

This works very well, but the performance is miserable.

Comment: This may help ... [extendtrue-deep-copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512773/jquery-extendtrue-obj-not-creating-a-deep-copy)

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer:
JQuery doesn't support deep cloning of user defined objects at the moment, but this library does:
[owl](http://oranlooney.com/deep-copy-javascript/)