# Deep copy to avoid "Can't execute code from a freed script"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a page that resides within a frameset (this cannot be changed).  The main page in frame 1 calls what is essentially a data loading page in frame 2.  The page in frame 2 passes back a wddx object as a function parameter.  Here is a very simple example:

Frame 2:

```
parent.content.newRoutes(newRouteList);
```

Frame 1 (named "content"):

```
function newRoutes(newRoutesContainerRouteRS) {
    routesContainer.route_rs.appendRecordSet(newRoutesContainerRouteRS, false);
}
```

This works fine.  However, later I load a new page into frame 2 to do some server side validation.  After doing so, the next time I try to do anything with the routesContainer object I get the following error in IE8:

```
Can't execute code from a freed script
```

I understand why this occurs.  The original page in frame 2 has been unloaded, so any references to objects or functions within it are no longer valid.  I assumed that I could easily fix this problem by making a deep copy of the object passed back to frame 1 like this:

```
function newRoutes(newRoutesContainerRouteRS) {
    // Deep copy
    copiedContainer = jQuery.extend(true, {}, newRoutesContainerRouteRS);

    routesContainer.route_rs.appendRecordSet(copiedContainer, false);
}
```

However, this still results in the same error message.  Why doesn't this method solve the problem?  Is jQuery.extend not creating a deep copy?  I tried turning the copiedContainer variable into an array so that the previous object would not be wiped out each time this function is run, but that did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this question?

[jquery.extend(true, [], obj) not creating a deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512773/jquery-extendtrue-obj-not-creating-a-deep-copy)

I bet your newRoutesContainerRouteRS includes complex objects and as stated there - extend only works with simple objects

Comment: Thank you; that looks like its probably the issue.  The question becomes, how does one get around that?  Someone posted a comment on that question linking to http://oranlooney.com/deep-copy-javascript/ which looked like it might help, but I've been unable to get it working correctly as of yet.

Comment: Thanks John; that's where I found the aforementioned link.  I'll try to spend some more time with it in the coming week or two to see if I can work out a good, simple solution.  If I can I'll post it here.