# How to clone an array in javascript without using JSON.stringify or JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array example `fruit` . I'd like to copy it as array `fruits2`, without keeping reference.

As in the following example reference is kept so `fruits` is modified.

---

```
var fruit = function (name){
    this.name = name;
}
var fruits = [];
fruits.push(new fruit('apple'));
fruits.push(new fruit('banana'));
fruits.push(new fruit('orange'));

var fruits2 = fruits;
fruits2.length = 0;
console.log(fruits);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vkdqur82/

---

Using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse does the trick but the objects in `fruits2` are not any longer of type `fruit` but are of general type `object`

```
var temp = JSON.stringify(fruits);
var fruits2 = JSON.parse(temp);
```

I would like to know an alternative approach which would keep inner object of `fruit`.

Comment: using jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/vkdqur82/4/

Comment: related using jquery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512773/jquery-extendtrue-obj-not-creating-a-deep-copy

Comment: http://oranlooney.com/deep-copy-javascript/

Comment: here is a method using Object.setPrototypeOf() to create new objects, not use JSON, not re-invoke Constructors, but still keep your custom Constructor's and the inherited methods, without promoting everything to own properties or iterating: http://jsfiddle.net/rndme/x3tz5kzc/ (only works in newer browsers, but it's the best solution)

Comment: @dandavis thanks for sharing, I am just wondering about cross browser compatibility as Object.setPrototypeOf() is Harmony (ECMAScript 6)

Comment: i know it works for Chrome and Firefox, and you can fake it anywhere with _ _proto_ _ support

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `slice`: `var fruits2 = fruits.slice();` should do it.

Your [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/ogxqrytp/), modified

See also: [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

****Edit**. I was a bit lazy, let's correct my answer to make up for that.

For an `Array` of just values `slice` is perfect. For an `Array` of objects or arrays or a mix of values/objects/arrays, the `Array` and `Object` elements of the `Array` to clone need cloning too. Otherwise they will be references to the original arrays or objects (so: not copies) and a change of one [of these references of arrays or objects] will be reflected in all 'clones' containing a reference to it.

To clone an `Array` of Arrays/Objects/mixed values `Array.map` is your friend. There are several methods to think of:

1. creating a new instance with old data
   `var fruits1 = fruits.map(function(v) {return new Fruit(v.name);});`
2. using JSON
   `var fruits2 = fruits.map(function(v) {return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(v));});`
3. create and use some cloning method
   `var fruits3 = fruits.map(function(v) {return cloneObj(v);});`

In case 3, a method for cloning could look like:

```
function cloneObj(obj) {
    function clone(o, curr) {
        for (var l in o){
            if (o[l] instanceof Object) {
                curr[l] = cloneObj(o[l]);
            } else {
                curr[l] = o[l];
            }
        }
        return curr;
    }
    
    return obj instanceof Array 
             ? obj.slice().map( function (v) { return cloneObj(v); } )
             : obj instanceof Object 
               ? clone(obj, {})
               : obj;
}
```

Using this `cloneObj` method, `Array.map` is obsolete.
You can also use `var fruitsx = cloneObj(fruits);`

The jsFiddle from the link above is modified to demonstrate these methods.

For `Array.map`, see again [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Or simply, `fruits.slice()` (with no args).

Comment: Yep, the zero was just habit, removed it.

Comment: that doesn't clone the object at all, it just makes a new list of the same objects. if you parse(stringify()), changing a new object doesn't affect the old. as coded, changes to old or new will appear in the other. i'm not saying that's a deal-breaker, but it's a huge difference from the JSON-based clone mentioned by the OP

Comment: @dandavis iwhat about using jquery for deepcopy... smt like... var fruis2 = $.extend(true, [], fruits) ??

Comment: @KooiInc but using the MAP method together with JSON methods will create the result with general 'objects', where instead I what keep the specific type of 'fruit'

Comment: Sorry for my lazyness, I hope my corrected answer will make things more clear. @GibboK: `$.extend` will keep references to objects within an `Array`, in other words will not really copy them.

Answer (score 2):

`slice` can do the trick.

You can also use `.map` but `.slice` is normally faster.

```
var copy = fruits.map(function(item) {return item});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a new array and use concat method, so that you concat all values from your array to the new array. Something like this:

```
var x = ["a","b"];
var a = [];
a = a.concat(x);
console.log(a);
```

I edited my poor answer.

Best regards.

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I answered from my mobile phone. It's first time I use it. Let's se if i can delete it. Thanks.